# using Blockly's addChangeListener() function from Dart (js interop)

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop, blockly

I've been writing some wrapper code to access the Blockly API from Dart, using dart:js.  All is going smoothly until I need to pass a function to one of Blockly's event registration functions on the JS side.

The function in question in Blockly is `addChangeListener()` (see https://developers.google.com/blockly/installation/code-generators).  It takes a 0-arg function as a callback.  So my goal is to wrap a Dart function, pass it over, and have that function get called when the event fires.

In Dart:

```dart
var blockly = context['Blockly'];

context['codeChangedCallback'] = (){
   print('This should work, right?');
};  

blockly.callMethod('addChangeListener', [context['codeChangedCallback']]);
```

When Blockly initializes, I get this stack trace:

[image: stack trace screen shot]

I'm hoping someone can point out something obvious that I've missed.

I have a feeling this may have to do specifically with the way blockly is handling the function internally, because I tried passing the function outside of blockly and it worked fine.

Comment: You'd be better off asking at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/blockly

Comment: I always start with SO @espertus. The workaround is easy enough anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the addChangeListener() callback has an arity of one, and Dart cares about arity.  Your call should look like:

```dart
var blockly = context['Blockly'];

blockly.callMethod('addChangeListener', [(var event) => print('Success!')]);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work

```dart
var blockly = context['Blockly'];

context['codeChangedCallback'] = (){
   print('This should work, right?');
};  

blockly.callMethod('addChangeListener', [(){
   print('This should work, right?');
}]);
```

Comment: I tried passing a unwrapped anonymous function.  That didn't work for me either.  I ended up creating a wrapper on the js side for it.